# auto answer when catching the phone with asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I am working with an asterisk software pbx.

I have an IP phone which is configured with asterisk.

What i want to do is make call to a special number when the user hangs the phone. I do not want him to have to compose a number.

Do you know if it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You have call, part A(caller) call to party B(called).

So.

You can setup your dialplan if B hangup, asterisk connect A with next number.

You can't setup your dialplan if A hangup, B connected to other number, except variant when you do connect A&B via conference(not via Dial command).

If you want phone call B when A get it, that called HOTLINE and it is feature of phone, not asterisk.

Comment: I made a mistake in my question: it is when the user picks up the phone i want to dial automatically a number. In other word, i do not want the user to type a number. Imagine it is a phone for emergency. Thanks

Comment: That called hotline and it is feature of PHONE or adapter. Asterisk NOT KNOW when user pickup phone, only when user end of dialling and phone start call. Hotline for sure supported by all sipura(now cisco SPA) phones and adapters.